# Convert Python script with using of Streamlit to .exe file

Tags: python, executable, streamlit

I am new to coding and everything and I have this problem, I have a simple script where I imported streamlit and no other library and I want to convert this script to .exe file. I have tried two ways: pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe. Both didn't work out, in the case of auto-py-to-exe the window appeared for a second and that's it. I imagined this .exe file to be able to open a browser tab where the app can be executed by other people who have the .exe file.

```
import streamlit as st
st.write("""
...
...
st.write(result)
```

I have tried two ways: pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe. Both didn't work out, in the case of auto-py-to-exe the window appeared for a second and that's it. I imagined this .exe file to be able to open a browser tab where the app can be executed by other people who have the .exe file.

Comment: [ask]: "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** — copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: Have you tried the solution outlined here? https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-deployment-as-an-executable-file-exe-for-windows-macos-and-android/6812